# How to Enable HTTPS in WordPress using .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have domain hubket.com, i have enabled https through godaddy. Now it properly enabled https , if you opened it.

Now, I want to convert into www or none www for all users like this http://www.hubket.com

I have tried to enable with few test codes in tutorials like this!

**Test 1**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
 # BEGIN WordPress
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Test 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Kindly help me to open https for all users.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, no need to make changes (like url):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Beside this htaccess snippet it is absolutely NECESSARY that you search and replace all http:// links in your DB with https://. For this you can I can recommend you [this script](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB).

Comment: i have edit the code as you suggested. but i am afraid to do DB script you have suggested me. Because might be it affects DB . any other or safe solution possible?

Comment: Of course it affects your database. Perform a backup before using this script and then replace your blog url with the https version of it

Comment: just updated replacement with your suggested script. now login forcefully done with https , but normal site is not forcefully opening with https, Still opening with non https

Comment: Check in WP Admin in settings what site url is set. If it's not HTTPS, set it.

Comment: 1 thing left only https is working fine, but in case of opening website https://www.hubket.com Mixed Content
The site includes HTTP resources.  lock symbol is not coming up

Comment: You probably have hardcoded links within your theme or in other settings... Check for this files: 'http://i.imgur.com/ht8r06U.png' and 'http://www.hubket.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/telephone.png'...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hubket\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hubket.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I have added, but still opening with non https , only opening like www.hubket.com , can you suggest any other solution

Comment: have you installed SSL certificate in your host?

Comment: Did you added the rewrite rule in hubket.com server htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Make sure to replace example.com with the domain name

Comment: I have posted first with dummy site name